# Conditional Expectation, is this true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I'd like to know if this statement is true:

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)|X\in A] = \int f(X) \mathbb{I}_{(X\in A)} dP
$$

for any $f(X)$ and $X$ random variables and $A\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your question needs more context. Why do you think it's true? What is your definition of the conditional expectation? Have you checked whether the right-hand side satisfies the definition? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You want $$ E[f(X)|X \in A] P[X \in A] = \int f(X) 1_{\{X \in A\}} dP$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true; just take $A$ to be an event with probability zero.

For example consider $X \sim U[0, 1]$, $f = \text{id}_\mathbb{R}$ and $A = \{\frac{1}{2}\}$. Then the left-hand side is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the right-hand side is zero.

Comment: What happens if $P(A)>0$?

Comment: It still won't be true in general. Consider a small neighbourhood around $\frac{1}{2}$ in the same example. The integrand on the right-hand side is less than $1$, so the integral is small, while the left-hand side is still close to $\frac{1}{2}$.